# Fazer slide dentro de uma div

Tags: javascript

Esse script faz um "slide" dentro do body.

Minha duvida é: Como faço para que o slide funcione dentro de uma div especifica ?

```
var imageCount = 0;

var currentImage = 0;

var images = new Array();

images[0] = 'img/01.jpg';

images[1] = 'img/02.png';

images[2] = 'img/03.jpg';


var preLoadImages = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
   if (images[i] == "")
   break;

   preLoadImages[i] = new Image();

   preLoadImages[i].src = images[i];

   imageCount++;
}

function startSlideShow()
{
   if (document.body && imageCount > 0)

   {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+images[currentImage]+")";  

      document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";

      document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";

      document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "left top";

      document.body.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";

      currentImage = currentImage + 1;

      if (currentImage > (imageCount-1))
      { 
         currentImage = 0;
      }
      setTimeout('startSlideShow()', 5000);
   }
}
startSlideShow();
```

Answer (score 1):

Atribua um id a sua div, no exemplo abaixo atribuí a id slide assim:

> HTML

```
<div id="slide"></div>
```

Formate a dimensão da div:

> CSS

```
#slide { width: 300px; height: 300px; }
```

E altere o seu código JavaScript para recuperar a div pelo ID dela. No meu teste precisei retirar a linha do código `slide.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";`

> JavaScript

```
var imageCount = 0;

var currentImage = 0;

var images = new Array();

images[0] = '1.png';

images[1] = '2.png';

images[2] = '3.png';

var slide = document.getElementById('slide');

var preLoadImages = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
   if (images[i] == "")
   break;

   preLoadImages[i] = new Image();

   preLoadImages[i].src = images[i];

   imageCount++;
}

function startSlideShow()
{
   if (slide && imageCount > 0)

   {
      slide.style.backgroundImage = "url("+images[currentImage]+")";  

      slide.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";

      slide.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";

      slide.style.backgroundPosition = "left top";

      currentImage = currentImage + 1;

      if (currentImage > (imageCount-1))
      { 
         currentImage = 0;
      }
      setTimeout('startSlideShow()', 5000);
   }
}
startSlideShow();
```

Obs: Mas ainda terá que resolver o problema que as imagens devem ser da mesma dimensão do tamanho que for definir no CSS.

Comment: Eu havia feito o mesmo procedimento mas não dava certo , var slide = document.getElementById("slide"); creio que era por causa das aspas duplas , coloquei aspas simples e funcionou *_*, Desde já agradeço pela ajuda !!

Comment: Então veja como votar e aceitar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour